# Unable to load new images from a directory in a bucket in google cloud storage in python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Previously, I have been loading images (blobs) from a bucket:

```
# connect to storage
storage_client = storage.Client(project_id)
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=img_dir)  # Get list of files
images = np.zeros((len(list(blobs)), height, width))

print(images.shape)
```

When I print the images shape, I can tell the array has the correct size (num_files x height, width) but when I try to load the blobs as PIL images like this:

```
# connect to storage
storage_client = storage.Client(project_id)
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=img_dir)  # Get list of files
filenames = []
i = 0
# show some images
for blob in blobs:

    filename = blob.name
    print(filename)
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(blob.download_as_bytes()))
```

the filename is only the directory ('/directory/') as if there are no files! so I get:

```
---> 13 img = Image.open(BytesIO(blob.download_as_bytes()))

File ~/miniconda/envs/myenv_local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py:3186, in open(fp, mode, formats)
   3184 for message in accept_warnings:
   3185     warnings.warn(message)
-> 3186 raise UnidentifiedImageError(
   3187     "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
   3188 )

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fa9ca4b8860>
```

This only happens with new files (uploaded recently to the bucket). If I run the same code for old files, I can load the images no problem.

Any ideas what the problem could be? or how to debug it?

Many thanks!!!

Comment: I just uploaded the new images to an old directory and I can load the new images too so this seems to be related to permissions of the objects in the new directory...

Comment: Please post this as an answer in order for other community members with similar question will find this helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RobertG but that was not the answer. I just solved the problem and submitted it as the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. For some reason

```
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=img_dir)
```

returns a list where the first element is the directory path, instead of the first file in the directory:

```
/path/images/
/path/images/file1.jpg
/path/images/file2.jpg
...
```

so to solve this, I just check that the blobs don't have a / at the end, which in that case is a file I can load normally.

Comment: Some tools will create objects of zero bytes with directory-like names `/path/images/` as a placeholder. This may be what's happened here.